# Maven not putting HTML properly to WAR

Tags: java, maven, wicket

I've made new maven module, from Wicket's quick start archetype. Pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>keeper</groupId>
<artifactId>keeper</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- TODO project name  -->
<name>quickstart</name>
<description></description>
<properties>
    <wicket.version>6.12.0</wicket.version>
    <jetty.version>7.6.13.v20130916</jetty.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!--  WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  JUNIT DEPENDENCY FOR TESTING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--  JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Apache Nexus</id>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

My problem is that Maven is not correcly putting htML files in WAR file. If my HTML file packeg location is: `com.company.project.HomePage.html` I though, that Maven will put this file in `com/company/project/` inside WAR's classes folder, meanwhile its in `com.company.project` directory (that's full name). So when I start Wicket's page there's exception:

```
Last cause: Can not determine Markup. Component is not yet connected to a parent. [Page class = pl.com.suadeo.keeperBrowser.HomePage, id = 2, render count = 1]
```

I've tried to change location in WebApplication config and changing HTML location but effect is the same:

```
@Override
public void init()
{
    super.init();

    // add your configuration here
    this.getResourceSettings().getResourceFinders().add( new WebApplicationPath( this.getServletContext(), "pages" ) );
}
```

Considering above setup, HTMLs should be located in WARs /pages folder (not inside WEB-INF?). Why there's problem with maven packaging?

At first, my HTML files were located next to corresponding Java classess (for example HomePage.java and HomePage.html in `src.main.java.com.company.project`). Next, after changing Wicket's config, I've tried to put them in `src.main.resources.pages`, `src.main.webapp.pages` and `src.main.webapp.WEB-INF.pages` but nothing worked

Comment: You haven't told us where you put these HTML files in your project.

Comment: Yea sorry, made an update

Answer (score 1):

My common way how to put files is to use the default markup resource finder. So that means put markup files into source directories. It means the code is in src/main/java/com/company/project/MyPage.java and the associated markup is in src/main/java/com/company/project/MyPage.html.

The maven configuration to include the markup into JAR (also WAR) is:

src/main/resources
            
                
            
            
                /*.java
            
        
        
            true
            src/main/java
            
                
            
            
                /*.java

```
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </testResource>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </testResource>
</testResources>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my HTML files under the `src/main/resources` folder and then following the package hierarchy. In your case would be:

```
src/main/resources/comcompany/project/HomePage.html
```

So that, I have java and html files separated but Maven will merge them together automatically (no further configuration is needed) when deploying.